# Functools.update_wrapper() doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators, functools

I use `Functools.update_wrapper()` in my decorator, but It seems like `update_wrapper` rewrites only function attributes (such as `__doc__`, `__name__`), but does not affect on `help()` function.

I aware of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973783/python-decorator-with-arguments-of-decorated-function), but they don't work with decorator-class.

Here is my function.

```
import functools

class memoized(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.func(*args)

@memoized 
def printer(arg):
    "This is my function"
    print arg
```

Here is the output

```
>>> printer.__doc__
This is my function

>>> help(printer)
Help on memoized in module __main__ object:

printer = class memoized(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args)
 |  
 |  __init__(self, func)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

It looks like a bug, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`functools.update_wrapper()` sets the attribute *on the instance*, but in Python versions up to 3.8, `help()` looks at the information *on the type*.

So `printer.__doc__` gives you the instance attribute, `help()` prints information about `type(printer)`, e.g. the `memoized` class, which does not have a `__doc__` attribute.

This was not considered a bug, this was all by design; [`help()` will always look at the class when you pass in an instance](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d4630b1c8792/Lib/pydoc.py#l1552). Don't use a class as decorator if you want `help()` to work for the decorated function, or upgrade your Python version.

This was eventually [changed in Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#pydoc), see the [bug report discussion](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84438).

Comment: So, there is no way to fix it, as long as I use a class as decorator?

Comment: @user3664218: indeed; `help()` gives you information about the class, not the instance, and if you want the latter you should not use a class decorator.

Comment: This means that class decorators are partly broken.  What's the justification for this design?

Comment: @NeilG the comments in the pydoc source are clear: because normally when you pass in an instance of something you typically want to document the methods available, not the instance attributes. That is the normal usecase. Pydoc cannot detect that here the instance is used as a replacement for a method, and that may be unfortunate but I'm not sure that you'd call it *broken*.

Comment: I think it's broken because using a class is a standard way and I the most versatile way to implement decorators.  One workaround that they should have considered would have been to have a `__helpobject__` magic method that defaults to `type(self) if not isinstance(self, type) else self`, which would allow classes that implement a decorator pattern to override this method.

Comment: @NeilG: Using a class to decorate is not all *that* standard; most decorators use functions (with a closure). I'd only use a class if I needed to implement custom binding behaviour or additional methods on the object. Decorators are a relatively late addition to Python, Pydoc is an older setup. If this issue is something enough people care about the core developers probably will come up with something. You can help by discussion ideas on Python-ideas or filing an issue on bugs.python.org.

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  For me, it's too small a wart for me to worry about posting it on ideas.  I don't think it belongs in bugs.  Come to think of it, if I've decorated something, I probably want help from the whole decoration chain, so I want to get the decorator's doc and the function's doc, and so on.  functools.wraps was always kind of ugly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you refer to `functools.wrapper()`.  You mean `functools.update_wrapper()` correct?

Comment: @pylang: ah, yes, in this case, I did. `functools.wrapper()` is the decorator that applies `functools.update_wrapper()`.