# Can I use aspects in python without changing a method / function's signature?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, aop

I've been using python-aspectlib to weave an aspect to certain methods - unfortunately this changes the methods signature to `Argspec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', default=None)`, which creates problems when working with libraries that depend on `inspect` returning the proper signature(s).

Is there a way to use python-aspectlib without changing a method's signature? If not, are there other python aspect libraries that can do this?

I've looked at the decorator module, which explicitly mentions the problem of changing a method signature: http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html#statement-of-the-problem , but I was hoping to find a solution where I don't need to modify the methods I want to weave (since they are part of a third party library).

I'm using python 2.7.6

Comment: if `aspectlib` is an open-source library; submit a patch that enables the preserving of function signatures. Related: [How you implemented your Python decorator is wrong](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/tree/master/blog)

Comment: It looks like before Python 3.3 you had to use `eval()` to set the correct function signature (as the `decorator` module does). In Python 3.3+ `wrapper.__signature__` is supported explicitly, [see PEP 362](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/).

Comment: This may help when you need to implement it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973783/python-decorator-with-arguments-of-decorated-function

Comment: aspectlib is an open source library - unfortunately my python knowledge isn't (yet) good enough to understand what they're doing (or actually patching it). Thanks for the links, they were very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to 'fix' this for my specific use case with the following piece of code:

```
from decorator import decorator
from Module1 import Class1
from Module2 import Class2

def _my_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):
    #add decorator code here
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


def my_decorator(f):
    return decorator(_my_decorator, f)

methods_to_decorate = [
    'Class1.method1',
    'Class2.method2',
    ]

for method in methods_to_decorate:
    exec_str = method + '= my_decorator('+method+'.im_func)'
    exec(exec_str)
```

This probably doesn't handle all of the issues mentioned in the [How you implement your Python decorator is wrong](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/tree/master/blog) blog posts, but it full fills the criteria most important to me: correct method signatures.