# Python ~ Importing a class that implements multiprocessing fails on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, class, multiprocessing

I have three files in a folder:

## MultiProcFunctions.py

The idea is to take any function and parallelize it

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager

def MultiProcDecorator(f,*args):

    """
    Takes a function f, and formats it so that results are saved to a shared dict
    """

    def g(procnum,return_dict,*args):
        result = f(*args)
        return_dict[procnum] = result

    g.__module__ = "__main__"

    return g

def MultiProcFunction(f,n_procs,*args):
    """
    Takes a function f, and runs it in n_procs with given args
    """

    manager     = Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    jobs = []
    for i in range(n_procs):
        p = multiprocessing.Process( target = f, args = (i,return_dict) + args )
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    return dict(return_dict)
```

## MultiProcClass.py

A file that defines a class which makes use of the above functions to parallelize the `sq` function:

```
from MultiProcFunctions import MultiProcDecorator, MultiProcFunction

def sq(x):
    return x**2

g = MultiProcDecorator(sq)

class Square:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self,x):
        return MultiProcFunction(g,2,x)
```

## MultiProcTest.py

Finally, I have a third file that imports the class above and tries to call the `f` method:

```
from MultiProcClass import Square

s = Square()
print s.f(2)
```

However, this yields an error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 528, in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
EOFError
```

I am on Windows 7, and also tried:

```
from MultiProcClass import Square

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Square()
    print s.f(2)
```

In this case, I got a different error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function g at 0x01F62530>: it's not found as __main__.g
```

Not sure how to make heads or tails of this. I get neither error on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, where all of this works flawlessly; so the error definitely has to do with how Windows does things, but I can't put my finger on it. Any insight is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you get it on Windows because under Windows you start a new Python process whereas in Linux you fork the process. That means in Windows you need to serialize and deserialize the function whereas in Linux the pointer can be used. Finding a function required module and nae of the function to point to it.

`g.__module__` should equal `f.__module__`.

Also [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973783/python-decorator-with-arguments-of-decorated-function) might help further how to decorate functions for picklability and usability.